# Finding a differentiable bijection $f(u,v)$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Let $(u,v) \in S^1$ be on the unit circle and $C > c > 0$ constants.

I am trying to find a differentiable bijection $(u,v) \mapsto f(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(u,v)$ satisfes $$\big(1+f(u,v)^2+C^2-c^2\big)^2 - 4C^2 = 0$$

Any hint or idea? I have been trying for a while and can't figure it out :(

Thanks.

Comment: Surely such a bijection is surjective and continuous? How can it map a compact set like $S^1$ onto a non-compact set like $\Bbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition means that $$(1+f(u,v)^2+C^2-c^2)^2$$ must be constant (equal to $4C^2$), which means that $1+f(u,v)^2+C^2-c^2$ can only ever equal $2C$ or $-2C$.

This means that $f(u,v)^2$ can only ever equal either $c^2-C^2-1-2C$ or $c^2-C^2-1+2C$.

In the first case, this means $f(u,v)$ can only be $\sqrt{c^2-C^2-1-2C}$ or $-\sqrt{c^2-C^2-1-2C}$, if the square root even exists.

In the second case, $f(u,v)$ can only be $\sqrt{c^2-C^2-1+2C}$ or $-\sqrt{c^2-C^2-1+2C}$, again, if the square root exists.

All in all, your condition means that $f(u,v)$ can only ever take *at most* four values, and therefore, it cannot be bijective. I say at most because, for example, if $C=3$ and $c=1$, then there is no real value that satisfies your condition.